# Prove by Heine that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{a^x}{x}=+\infty$ for $a>1$

Tags: calculus

I want to prove the following using Heine's definition: 
$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{a^x}{x}=+\infty$ for $a>1$

How can I show that all sequences diverges to $\infty$. I thought Heine's definition is used for disproving a limit. 
I would also appreciate if you could show me how to do it using Cauchy's definition (just to assert my work fits the definition).

Thank you

Comment: Can you use any expansion? (I mean Taylor series).

Comment: Theoretically yes, but I want to prove it using Heine and Cauchy

Answer (score 2):

Heine's definition of continuity states that for a function $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb R$ converges to a limit $\ell$ at a point $a\in\overline{A}$ (the closure of $A$) if and only if $f(u_n)$ converges to $\ell$ for any sequence converging to $a$.

Applying the definition with $A = \mathbb R$ and $a = +\infty$, we see that for every sequence $u$ converging to $+\infty$,
$$
\ln\left(\frac{a^{u_n}}{u_n}\right) = u_n\ln(a) - \ln(u_n) \sim \ln(a)u_n \rightarrow +\infty
$$
because $\ln(a) > 0$ resulting from $a > 1$ and $\ln(x) =_{+\infty} o(x)$ using Landau's little-o notation.

Thus, applying the exponential function to the previous limit yields that
$$
\frac{a^{u_n}}{u_n} \longrightarrow +\infty.
$$

**Using Cauchy's definition** Let $M > 0$. We want to find a $k > 0$ such as $a^x/x > M$ whenever $x > k$. Going to log, we get the condition
$$
x\ln(a) > \ln(Mx) > \ln(Mk)
$$
i.e.
$$
x > \frac{\ln(Mk)}{\ln(a)}
$$
Thus it is sufficient that
$$
k > \frac{\ln(Mk)}{\ln(a)}
$$
which holds for sufficiently large $k$.

Comment: Why did you prove it for ln and how does that help? Also, can you explain this transition - $ u_n\ln(a) - \ln(u_n)$ ?

Comment: The logarithm function verifies $\ln(a^b)= b\ln(a)$ for all positive $a$ and real $b$, as well as $\ln(a/b) = \ln(a) - \ln(b)$ for all positive $a$ and $b$. Using these two identities gives $\ln(a^{u_n}/u_n) = \ln(a^{u_n})-\ln(u_n) = u_n\ln(a) - \ln(u_n)$.

Comment: How do you know the last inequality holds for large $k$, this seems the same as what you are trying to prove.

Comment: It's again the argument that $\ln(k) =_{+\infty} o(k)$. For any factor $\epsilon > 0$, we can take sufficiently large $k$ such that $\ln(Mk) < \epsilon Mk$ and with $\epsilon = \ln(a) > 0$ we get what we want.

Comment: Is there more elegant way to show it without using o notation?

Comment: If you don't know it, you can still show that for every $\epsilon > 0$, you can find $b > 0$ such that $$\ln(x) <\epsilon x $$ for $x > b$. You only have to show that the function $x\longmapsto \ln(x) - \epsilon x$ is strictly decreasing after some point and has at least one point where it's negative.